CSS wrappable flex row, weird gap when trying to add line break when container height is fixed (or 100% parent)
I'm trying to add linebreak to wrappable flex row items.
It basicaly work, but i have a gap i don't understand.
I don't have a specific pattern, it comes from a setting file (So i want to rely on responsiveness of flexbox)
I want the render to use fill all the container space with items separated with breaks. I made the container wrappable to let items wraps in case of small screens (like phones).
Example pattern with a line group of 2 items, followed by two lines group of 3 items.
<div class="container">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="break"></div>

<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="break"></div>

<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
</div>

  
.container{
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:500px;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  gap: 5px
}

.item {
  align-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  min-width:150px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border:black solid 1px;
  background-color:silver;
  
}

.break {
  flex-basis:100%;
  height:0;
}

jsfiddle
You see on the image the gap (in blue) i don't underestand, i want the .item to by stretched
rendered page
Thank you

align-content: start to your container then set any height you want for the items

i don't want to set height to my items, i want them to use all the container space, with align-content only, the items are smaller: https://jsfiddle.net/9L2kq7f0/

it's not possible with break elements. Are you looking for a specific pattern? like 2 - 3 - 3 elements per row?

yes, but it is an unknow pattern. I wan't the items to wrap and have the same height on smaller screen (like phone). I tried to use alternance between flex column and row Has almost what i want. But each group have the same heights and then items divides in group height (so group of two items have two bigger items than group of 3 items)

what do you mean by "unknown"? You need to actually know the pattern to build it and place the break elements

the patern come from a settings file (an array of array) then i build the html with vuejs. So i don't know if the settings say i have a group of 2 then group of 3 then group of 1 or something else

better edit your question to talk about the pattern issue you need to create rather than focus on the "break" elements you are adding. You will have more chance to get answers than with your actual question

Set the height of the .item class to 100% and remove the break div from the HTML, as well as the .break class from the CSS.
.item {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 150px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: silver;
  height: 100%;
}

Explanation:
The container has a height of 500px, so all items within this container will take up 100% height. The break div serves no purpose here; simply giving height to the item div will automatically stretch items to the available space of the container.

Hi, thank for responding. For my purpose i want to set my line-break manually (here after item 2 and 5). And have responsive layout for smaller screen (in case of phone, items 1 and 2 wraps, etc...)

then you should use grid instead of flex and use media query to show certain columns on smaller devices, grid approach is appropriate than flex for multiple rows data. Thank you

I'm not familiar with css grid but I have the impression that we have to choose the number of columns in advance. My app doesn't know if the settings will indicate 1 or 2 or 15 columns for a line...
